# Empty response body

Tags: node.js, superagent

I am using [superagent](http://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/) to make a request to [Vimeo's Upload API](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload#generate-upload-streaming-ticket).

My request looks as follows =

```
var request = require('superagent');

request
    .post('https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos')
    .set('Authorization', 'bearer ' + myAccessToken)
    .set('Accept', 'application/vnd.vimeo.*+json;version=3.2')
    .send({ type: "streaming" })
    .end(function (error, response) {
        //Code
    }
```

I have to use the `Accept` header here to specify the version as mentioned in their [documentation](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/spec#version) .
My problem is that the `response.body` is an empty object `{}`. The `response.text` is `undefined` - The `response.status` is 201.

I should get the response as shown in the documentation. But I get an empty object instead.
If I try the same request through POSTMAN, I get the response that I need. But using `superagent` I am not able to get it. Is there any additional configuration I need to do to get the response.body?

Comment: Can you show the code that works?  It would be helpful to compare the two.

Comment: I'm having a similar problem with Superagent 8.0.6 where nothing inside `.end()` is executed.